# Sand art on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, art

Is it Hallachicly permissible to make [Sand art](http://www.sandartsupplies.com/) on Shabbos or is it prohibited on Shabbos and if so what prohibition are you doing maybe writing?

Comment: This question would be much improved if you would explain what Sandart is, or, at least, link to a page that explains it well, and if you would explain your reasons for thinking it might be forbidden.

Comment: Some possible issues:
Is the Sandart permanent?  Does it require glue or other materials?  
Do you have to sort out the different colors?
Could mixing the colors be considered dyeing?

Comment: @msh210 Sandart is drawing pictures by pouring sand in a narrow stream to make patterns and designs. It's intended to be temporary for those who do it as a form of idol worship (Sand mandala). But of course it can be just art as well.

Answer (score 3):

No, because by using sand in this form it's a form of drawing, which is a biblically prohibited act on shabbat. Even if something is not permanent (for example, writing letters on frost on your window), this would at least be rabinically prohibited.

Comment: where do we see that it is a form of drawing?

Comment: @MosheYitzhak, when you use sand in this fashion, you're making it into a drawing, albeit one made of sand. The whole point of using colored sand is to be able to make some kind of art.

Comment: I've seen abstract sand art that seems to aim for the aesthetics of colors and shapes but doesn't depict anything.  I'm not sure that counts as drawing.